# How do you get stack to pass custom flags to ghc (and the cpp preprocessor)?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have some conditional compilation in my files, say

```
#if FLAG
bogus1 x = x + 1
#else
bogus2 x = x + 2
#endif
```

Then I'm trying to set my `package.yaml` to pass the flag to `ghc` on build. So I added the following to the file:

```
executables:
  my_maim:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - "-DFLAG"
    - -main-is Main
    dependencies:
    - MyPackage
```

This does not work (I still see `bogus2`) but it gives me a useful warning `Warning: Instead of 'ghc-options: -DFGLAG' use 'cpp-options: -DFGLAG'`. Fair enough, so I tried:

```
executables:
  my_maim:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    cpp-options:
    - "-DFLAG"
    ghc-options:
    - -main-is Main
    dependencies:
    - MyPackage
```

Then building with `stack build` does not pass the right flags (I still see `bogus2`).

On the other hand, I can do `stack build -ghc-options --DFLAG`, which works! (I finally see `bogus1`).

What am I doing wrong, and how do you set stack to pass the right flags?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are using that flag in files other than `Main.hs`. The options under `executables:` only affect `app/Main.hs`. You can put your `cpp-options:` config at the toplevel or under `library:` instead.

```
# Toplevel (indentation 0)
cpp-options:
- -DFLAG
```

```
library:
  # ... (other fields)
  cpp-options:
  - -DFLAG
```

Comment: The former worked, but the latter did not.